# what is the difference between rated power and power rating?

Tags: resistors, terminology

Very appreciated if anyone can explain the difference between **rated power** and **power rating**. I used to see both of them in electronic magazine.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE - can you provide some context such as *where* you have seen these terms used?

Comment: @PeterSmith Thanks so much for your response. As I saw that in the library of my school, I am so sorry that it is not so convenient to provide some context here, but I found some context via Google, please take a look at these two datasheet,[Resistor1](http://www.vishay.com/docs/49873/49873_sg2113.pdf), [Resistor2](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1755795.pdf). Resistor1 Has **Rated Power**, Resistor2 has the **Power Rating**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context they are synonymous.

The rated power or power rating of a resistor is specified over temperature with [derating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derating) applied above a particular temperature.

Here is the electrical specification for a particular resistor:
[image: CC1 resistor]

Comment: There could also be a semantic aspect to this. Rated power is the 0.04 W value and power rating is the entire entry including the temperature details.